# With Locust, how can you access a specific locust-user from within a task?

Tags: locust

I am using Locust to send various http requests to an endpoint.  The endpoint may sometimes return a 401, indicating that the locust user needs a new bearer token. Does locust provide a way to access the locust-user that is making the given call?

I would like to do be able to add seomthing like WebUser.login() if a 401 is returned from the server

```
class WebUser(HttpUser):
    tasks = {LoadTasks}
    bearer = ""
    on_start = login() //gets a bearer-token for the 'bearer' field.


class LoadTasks(TaskSet):
    endpointPath = "/domain/subdomain/endpoint"

    @task(5)
    def put(self):
        path = self.endpointpath
        response = self.client.put()
                                                           
        if response.status_code == 401:
            // WebUser to call authorization endpoint and retrieve new access_token
            // i.e. locust-user.login()
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to worry about doing anything special. Locust will take the code you write in your tasks and run it as each user automatically, sort of abstracting away the concurrency. Write your code as if you're going to run it as a single user and almost always it should work.

All of that is just to say that, yes, your code should work as-is to do you what you want. You can just do a check for a 401 like that and tell it to request a new token if so.

Comment: but how how can I access the "bearer" property of the WebUser from inside the "put" task?

Comment: Don't store it there. Store it inside the `LoadTasks` class.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:
https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/tasksets.html#tasksets

> The TaskSet instance contains a reference to the User - self.user. It also has a shortcut to its User’s client attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `catche_response` option in locust.

Edit your code like this:

```
class WebUser(HttpUser):
    tasks = {LoadTasks}
    bearer = ""
    on_start = login() //gets a bearer-token for the 'bearer' field.


class LoadTasks(TaskSet):
    endpointPath = "/domain/subdomain/endpoint"

    @task(5)
    def put(self):
        requester(client=client)
                
def requester(client, headers = None, retryCount = 0):
    path = self.endpointpath
    
    with client.put(path, headers=headers, catch_response=True) as response:
    
        if response.status_code == 200:
                response.success()
        elif response.status_code == 401:           
            if retryCount < 5:
                // WebUser to call authorization endpoint and retrieve new access_token
                token = login()
                headers = {
                    "Authorization": "Bearer <your_token>"
                }
                requester(client = client, headers = None, retryCount = retryCount+1)
            else:
                response.failure("Token not set or login failed after 5 time retry")
        else:
            // log wrong status code in failure log in locust web tool
            response.failure(f"Request failed with {response.status_code=}")
```

*Note that* implementing of login function is neccessary.